# How get the default Sharepoint AlertTemplates

Tags: c#, templates, sharepoint, sendmail, alert

I'm trying to create an own function to send an alert mail from SP. I know there are default Alerts and methods that send them. But for my situation I need to send them manually.

My main question is how I can get an alerttemplate (SPAlertTemplate) from the file that provides the templates:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\alerttemplates.xml
```

So the manually send mails look the same as the default alert mails.

what i try to accomplish would be in code:

```
SPAlertTemplate = ?.Get(SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList);
```

or

```
SPAlertTemplate = ?.[SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList];
```

But I have no idea what function is responsible for storing/managing these templates or if this is even the right way to get a default template.

Thanks in advance

Oxillery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     SPAlertTemplateCollection atc = new SPAlertTemplateCollection((SPWebService)site.WebApplication.Parent);
     SPAlertTemplate newTemplate = atc["SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList"];
```

I just posted a much more thorough solution here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/how-can-i-create-custom-alerts-for-external-email-addresses/76086#76086